# Magento 2: "There was a category move error"/"Something went wrong while saving the category"

Tags: magento-2.1, category, error, category-tree, exception

We are experiencing issues when trying to move or save a category in Magento 2.1.8

Trying to move a category results in:

```
There was a category move error.
```

Whilst trying to save gives this error:

```
Something went wrong while saving the category.
```

The following in the exception log is one clue:

```
main.CRITICAL: InvalidArgumentException: indexMethod must be one of  in
/home/site/websites/www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/TemporaryTableService.php:103
```

The only other error being in the console:

```
VM1871:6 Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom
```

I've found people with similar errors on Google, but none with this exception.

I've tried:

- Reindexing
- Clearing caches
- Recompiling
- Truncating the url_rewrite table

But nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Geat,  donot get proper  error message. First open `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save` .Find ` $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong while saving the category.'));` change  to ` $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());` tell message what is the issue

Comment: Thanks, Amit. It gives me the same error that I saw in the logs: "indexMethod must be one of", and that's the entire error string. It's like the whole request to write to the database is empty.

Comment: i guess that some tabl related to product was corrupt that why it is happeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user dakzilla over on GitHub had the same issue, and his solution worked for me.

During the upgrade from 2.1.7 to 2.1.8 (in my case), app/etc/di.xml was not updated properly.

Adding the following lines to the file (after comparing my file to that in the official download) and recompiling got rid of the errors.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\TemporaryTableService">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="allowedIndexMethods" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="HASH" xsi:type="string">HASH</item>
      <item name="BTREE" xsi:type="string">BTREE</item>
    </argument>
    <argument name="allowedEngines" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="INNODB" xsi:type="string">INNODB</item>
      <item name="MEMORY" xsi:type="string">MEMORY</item>
      <item name="MYISAM" xsi:type="string">MYISAM</item>
    </argument>
  </arguments>
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution, but at least it will bring you closer to it. It's `vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/CurrentUrlRewritesRegenerator.php` and `vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Product/CurrentUrlRewritesRegenerator.php` getting the wrong entity type info (`ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE` returns 'product' instead of 4, `CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE` is 'category' instead of 3)